# Passing a function to the jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

I already know about the advantages of wrapping your Javascript in a function like this:

```
(function () {
    // code goes here
}())
```

But I've seen some scripts which accomplish this by passing the wrapper function to the jQuery object:

```
$(function () {
    // blah blah blah blah blah
});
```

What's the advantage of doing it this way, or is it just a matter of personal taste? And does doing it the second way negate the need for `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: This first one is a function that is executed immediately, the second one is the jQuery syntax to execute something on page load, and yes it is a replacement for $(document).ready()

Comment: Second is the same as `$(document).ready()`. Read here in the docs http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one

```
(function () {
    // code goes here
}())
```

[That is self executing function.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript)

And the second function is `jquery` specific.

[If you see the docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document, so the selector can be omitted.

The .ready() method is typically used with an anonymous function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Which is equivalent to calling:

```
$(function() {
     // Handler for .ready() called.
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is just standard JavaScript a self executing function, the second one is jQuery specific, and is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function () {});`

see [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript) for more info on self executing functions

Answer (score 0):

`(function(){}())` is an IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression) and is just an function executing Immediately
`$(function(){})` is an jQuery callback fro when the browser is ready

i often have to add jQuery to sites that have mootools on them so to avoid $ conflicts i do somthing like this:

```
;(function($, app, undefined){
    // code here
}(jQuery, myApp = window.myApp || {}))
```